# Fixed-Rate sampling in Application Insights poor accuracy

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

For analytics purposes, I would need to analyze the number of requests that are made to my server and I am using Application Insights.
Since the data is massive, to limit costs I decided to apply a Fixed-Rate Sampling of 5%.
After doing some tests I got the following results:

- 800 real requests -> 32 samples (4%)
- 200 real requests -> 14 samples (7%)

I expected a sampling rate of 5% but my empirical data shows poor accuracy.
Is this behavior normal? Why does this happen? Can I consider the data to be representative in case of high requests volume?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#how-sampling-works?

Comment: Sure. I want to know if someone expert about Application Insights could give me advices or more explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sampling in Application Insights is done using randomized approach:

- When a new span starts an operation id is randomly generated
- Operation id is hashed and converted to number in [0..1] range
- If this number is less or equal than configured sampling ratio then telemetry is sampled in, discarded otherwise

5% does not mean that every 20th document is collected. So, on small numbers you indeed can see variance away from configured 5%. On bigger numbers this should get closer and closer to 5% (as with any random distribution).

Here is a sample code which illustrates it (this is *not* how Application Insights implemented it, this just illustrates how random-based sampling works):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();

        const int numRuns = 50;
        const int numPerRun = 200;
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numRuns; j++)
        {
            int totalPerRun = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numPerRun; i++)
            {
                var next = random.Next(100);
                if (next < 5)
                {
                    ++totalPerRun;
                    ++total;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Run #{j}: {totalPerRun} out of {numPerRun}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Total: {total} out of {numRuns * numPerRun}");
    }
```

Here is the output. Note, that out of **10,000** we got almost **5%**. But on individual runs it varied way beyond 5%:

```
Run #0: 12 out of 200
Run #1: 6 out of 200
Run #2: 12 out of 200
Run #3: 7 out of 200
Run #4: 8 out of 200
Run #5: 8 out of 200
Run #6: 6 out of 200
Run #7: 12 out of 200
Run #8: 7 out of 200
Run #9: 11 out of 200
Run #10: 18 out of 200
Run #11: 11 out of 200
Run #12: 9 out of 200
Run #13: 11 out of 200
Run #14: 11 out of 200
Run #15: 10 out of 200
Run #16: 13 out of 200
Run #17: 7 out of 200
Run #18: 9 out of 200
Run #19: 15 out of 200
Run #20: 4 out of 200
Run #21: 6 out of 200
Run #22: 9 out of 200
Run #23: 8 out of 200
Run #24: 10 out of 200
Run #25: 10 out of 200
Run #26: 6 out of 200
Run #27: 13 out of 200
Run #28: 9 out of 200
Run #29: 5 out of 200
Run #30: 15 out of 200
Run #31: 9 out of 200
Run #32: 9 out of 200
Run #33: 12 out of 200
Run #34: 10 out of 200
Run #35: 8 out of 200
Run #36: 13 out of 200
Run #37: 8 out of 200
Run #38: 10 out of 200
Run #39: 9 out of 200
Run #40: 8 out of 200
Run #41: 6 out of 200
Run #42: 10 out of 200
Run #43: 11 out of 200
Run #44: 14 out of 200
Run #45: 10 out of 200
Run #46: 7 out of 200
Run #47: 13 out of 200
Run #48: 13 out of 200
Run #49: 9 out of 200
Total: 487 out of 10000
```